# Application of convergence of Fibonacci series

Tags: prime-numbers, fibonacci-numbers

'There are infinite prime numbers' is a fact that can be deduced by 'reciprocal of primes diverges' statement, so from this can we deduce the fact that

--> 'there are finite Fibonacci numbers in prime number series' since 'reciprocal of Fibonacci numbers converges but of primes, it diverges !' ??

Comment: For every $n$ let $p_n$ be the smallest prime larger than $n^2$. Then $\sum \frac{1}{p_n}$ converges.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you are trying to use a "fact" of the following sort:

**Possible Proposition.**

We know that if a series $S$ diverges, then its associated sequence has infinitely many terms.

Thus, if a series $T$ converges, then only finitely many elements of the associated sequence for $T$ can be in the associated sequence for $S$.

---

But this is, in general, false.

**Counterexample:** Consider $\sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}}\frac{1}{n} = \infty$ and $\sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}}\frac{1}{n^2} < \infty$ and reason from there.

So: No.